# What is known about the motivation of heroin addicts to quit?

Tags: addiction

I am curious to know what heroin addicts self-report regarding if they are or are not motivated to quit heroin, and why.

(For example, do some people enjoy using heroin but are socially pressured or stigmatized to quit, do some people feel that they cannot function normally while using heroin, etc.)

Comment: Your example falls far short of the depths to which addiction can carry the addict and sometimes their families or others around them. Are you perhaps referring to casual users instead? Remember to show your research when posting a question. There are many [testimonials](https://www.healthpartners.com/blog/a-full-time-job-in-hell-my-journey-in-and-out-of-opioid-addiction/) (mild example) you might read to glean some insight. Reading advice given to families could give some pointers too.